# Using variables in ansible script after fetching from csv files inside a loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am new to Ansible. I want to know how I can read an excel or csv file inside Ansible, store the information in variables and work with those variables.

Actually I want to create VMs. I will use the csv files to get the details (like hostname, partition details, IP details) of the VMs.

If somebody can help me in this regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [read_csv – Read a CSV file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/read_csv_module.html#read-csv-read-a-csv-file) module. For example the playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - read_csv:
        path: vms.csv
        key: hostname
      register: vms
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }}:
              {{ item.value.hostname }},
              {{ item.value.partition }},
              {{ item.value.ip }}"
      loop: "{{ vms.dict|dict2items }}"
```

with the file

```
$ cat vms.csv
hostname,partition,ip
hostname1,/dev/sda1,10.1.0.21
hostname2,/dev/sda1,10.1.0.22
hostname3,/dev/sda1,10.1.0.23
```

gives

```
  msg: 'hostname1: hostname1, /dev/sda1, 10.1.0.21'
  msg: 'hostname2: hostname2, /dev/sda1, 10.1.0.22'
  msg: 'hostname3: hostname3, /dev/sda1, 10.1.0.23'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply Vladimir. I have got the knowledge at least how to start.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to get Ansible to see one of the fields as a list? Say, if you had multiple partitions. I tried several things but couldn't get it to be read in as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my ansible code. This is what worked for me

playbook.yaml

```
---
- name: Read Users
  gather_facts: True
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - read_csv:
      path: users.csv
    register: userlist

  - debug: 
      msg: "{{ user.username }} and password is {{ user.password }}"
    loop: "{{ userlist.list }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: user
```

users.csv

```
username,password
user0,test123
user1,test123
```

Ansible Output

```sh
PLAY [Read Users] *************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [read_csv] ****************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={u'username': u'user0', u'password': u'test123'}) => {
    "msg": "user0 and password is test123"
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={u'username': u'user1', u'password': u'test123'}) => {
    "msg": "user1 and password is test123"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```